# Gdal_Translate -Projwin giving Error (Error while crease Subset from Image)

Tags: gdal-translate

"C:\Program Files\QGIS Las\OSGeo4W.bat" gdal_translate -of EHDR -projwin 39
10865.0 330905.0 3894865.0 335885.0 E:\F\CLP_BLD.img C:\Users\kailash\Desktop\gg
g\C_Output_LOWER_CENTRAL_VALLEY_2m_Z11N_1_DTM.bil
Input file size is 18480, 15670

**ERROR 1: Error: Computed -srcwin 1.80597e+006 1.79765e+006 -8000 -2490 has negat
ive width and/or height.**

Can any body help to run Gdal_tranlate -projwin command

Comment: Why are there 5 numbers here `-projwin 39 10865.0 330905.0 3894865.0 335885.0`? Are these supposed to be decimal degrees?

Comment: Can you add the extent of the file?

Comment: I suppose there is an extra space in the first coordinate, and the order should be upper-left-x upper-left-y lower-right-x lower-right-y, so the command should be  -projwin 3894865.0 335885.0 3910865.0 330905.0

Comment: Still it is not giving correct results, when giving this command output is not opening ...."C:\Program Files\QGIS Las\OSGeo4W.bat" gdal_translate -of EHDR -projwin 3894865.000000 335885.000000 3910865.000000 330905.000000 CLP_BLD.img out.Bil  do we need to define input projection and output also?

Answer (score 1):

The parameters for the gdal_translate -projwin command are ulx, uly, lrx and lry and they are equivalent to xMin, yMax, xMax and  yMin. Accordingly I switched the coordinates and got the correct results.